# GCM Notification not working

Tags: android, cordova

i`m developing an app with phonegap and using GCM for Push Notification, but i cann`t receive any Notification however Google Server return Message ID and i guess that it successful Message.

that is My MainFest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="MyPackageName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="MyPackageName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="MyPackageName.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_Test"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
        android:name="Test"
        android:label ="@string/title_activity_Test" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

<receiver
android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="MyPackageName" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
```

My GCMIntentService.java

```
package MyPackageName;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

public GCMIntentService() {

}

@Override
protected void onError(final Context arg0, final String arg1) {

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(final Context arg0, final Intent arg1) {

    String message = "";
    if (arg1.getExtras() != null) {
        final Bundle extras = arg1.getExtras();
        if (extras.containsKey("message")) {
            message = extras.getString("message");
        }
    }

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setContentTitle("Test").setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    final Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    final TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    try {
        final Uri notification = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        final Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
    }
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(final Context arg0, final String arg1) {

}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(final Context arg0, final String arg1) {

}
```

}

and Calling That Function to register at MainActivity.

```
private String RegisterWithGCM()
{           
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, "MySenderID");
      regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    } else {
      Log.v("Registration", "Already registered, regId: " + regId);
    }
    try{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Reg").setMessage(regId).setNeutralButton("CLose", null).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    return regId;
}
```

and at server side, i tried two ways

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "key=" + serviceKey);
            var nameValues = new NameValueCollection
                     {
                         {"registration_id", registrationId},
                         {"collapse_key", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                         {"data.payload", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message)}
                     };
            var resp = wc.UploadValues("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", nameValues);
            var respMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(resp);

        }
```

and

```
  var value = "test";
        System.Net.WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        System.IO.Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        System.Net.WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        System.IO.StreamReader tReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
```

and this is Google Server Respone

id=0:1378735596819604%5511fa701fcc42e9 
so Please any Help???

Comment: Are you sure the server is actually sending the notification?

Comment: that is the server reply.id=0:1378735596819604%5511fa701fcc42e9

Comment: That's google reply? Something not right. Google usually replies with the devices ids that you sent the notification to.

Check: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

Comment: Please see my server code.

Comment: I don't see any place where you put your android device ID.
As an example of GCM client and GCM server follow this link:
http://avilyne.com/?p=267. As for a google response you should get something like this:

 {"multicast_id":8594338261894783737,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1355822022916886%8ae6056ef9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: i followed the steps at the link but also with the same response.

Comment: Log.v("Registration", "Already registered, regId: " + regId); <-- Do you get a registration id?

Can't seem to find the error. You can also add this to your manifest, but I don't think is required: <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true"/>

Comment: i tried this but also the same server reply.

Comment: i used this tutorial http://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/gcm-demo/ and it`s working . thnx alot

Comment: You Should use that link in answer and accept your own answer so that people that come by know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this tutorial

**androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/gcm-demo**

and it`s working.

Answer (score 0):

I have [here](https://github.com/isnyaga/GCM-notification) a working copy of the one that is listed by [Google as a demo](http://code.google.com/p/gcm).

Download it and take a look at the implementation.